# Programmatically call WCF: identity check failed

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I'm migrating from App.config to programmatically, to call a WCF service with client certificate authentication/identity. The new code is .NET Core but the target framework of the test console app has been set to net472 so that it runs in Azure Kudu.

I've searched everywhere but cannot get rid of this error message.

Error:

Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The identity check failed for the outgoing message. The expected identity is 'identity(http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/right/possessproperty: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/thumbprint)' for the 'net.tcp://myserver:1001/MyServiceRelay/MyServiceRelay.svc' target endpoint.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.IdentityVerifier.EnsureIdentity(EndpointAddress serviceReference, AuthorizationContext authorizationContext, String errorString)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.EnsureOutgoingIdentity(SecurityToken token, SecurityTokenAuthenticator authenticator)

App.config:

```
<endpoint name="MyEndpoint"
                address="[PLACEHOLDER]"
                binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpAzureBinding"
                behaviorConfiguration="AzureCertificateBehavior"
                contract="MyCalledService">
        <identity>
          <certificate encodedValue="[PLACEHOLDER]" />
        </identity>
 </endpoint>

<netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpAzureBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="20485760">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="20485760" maxStringContentLength="20485760" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
 </netTcpBinding>

<behavior name="AzureCertificateBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate storeName="My" storeLocation="CurrentUser" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="[PLACEHOLDER]" />
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
 </behavior>
```

Equivalent in code:

```
// My FindCertificate method performs a lookup by thumbprint, exactly the same code that below when using "SetCertificate".
X509Certificate2 certificate = Common.FindCertificate(settings.CertificateThumbprint);
        var binding = new NetTcpBinding
        {
            // custom constant
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = Common.MaxReceivedMessageSize
        };
        // custom constant
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = Common.MaxArrayLength;
        // custom constant
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = Common.MaxStringContentLength;

        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;

        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(settings.MailService.EndpointAddress), EndpointIdentity.CreateX509CertificateIdentity(certificate));

        _channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMailService>(binding, endpoint);

        _channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, settings.CertificateThumbprint);
        _channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
        _channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
```

What is wrong? Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Well, nothing was "wrong" but the error message was not satisfying. Once I got it, I just had to replace:

```
EndpointIdentity.CreateX509CertificateIdentity(certificate)
```

by:

```
EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(settings.MailService.EndpointDns)
```

in the endpoint identity initialization. And the expected value was in the error message...

What helped me was to set up a channel factory that initializes by reading the classical .config file to a configuration class:

```
        ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "MailService.config";
        Configuration newConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        _channelFactory = new ConfigurationChannelFactory<IMailService>("MyEndpoint", newConfiguration, new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://myserver:1001/MyServiceRelay/MyServiceRelay.svc"));
```

(well, this didn't succeed in calling the endpoint, just gave a clue).

Still open question: why did the classical configuration work without complaining about the endpoint DNS? I checked it again. I read things back to 2010 about this security check (prevents phising). Also useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/service-identity-and-authentication

Comments are welcome.